# Parse date to datetime format in python

Tags: python, datetime

Can someone help me in parsing the date like this to datetime format

```
'Oct. 1, 2020'
```

Thanks

Comment: please have a look at `strptime` and show some effort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
from datetime import datetime

my_date = 'Oct. 1, 2020'

my_date_object = datetime.strptime(my_date, '%b. %d, %Y')

print(my_date_object)  # datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: You dont need to replace `.` and `,` . Just add them to the date format `"%b. %d, %Y"`